# The script mediator error in WSO2AM 1.5

Tags: wso2, mediator

***I try to add a sequence which contains a java script mediator as below :***

```
"<sequence name="response">
    <script language="js">
        mc.setPayloadXML(
        &lt;greeting&gt;Hello World&lt;/greeting&gt;
        );
    </script>
    <header name="To" action="remove"/>
    <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>       
    <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
    <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
    <send/>
    <log level="full"/>
</sequence>"
```

***Howerver,it occurs a error once I press the Update Button,the whole function stack is shown in the log, I check the jar "bsf-all,3.0.0.wso2v2" and it really contains the missing class and the jar is shown in the bundles info "bsf-all,3.0.0.wso2v2,../plugins/bsf-all_3.0.0.wso2v2.jar,4,true" :***
    "**com/sun/phobos/script/javascript/RhinoScriptEngineFactory** {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver}
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at ......
    **Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/phobos/script/javascript/RhinoScriptEngineFactory**
    at  org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.initScriptEngine(ScriptMediator.java:475)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.initInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:341)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.(ScriptMediator.java:146)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(ScriptMediatorFactory.java:105)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.createMediator(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:91)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getMediator(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:223)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractListMediatorFactory.addChildren(AbstractListMediatorFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.SequenceMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(SequenceMediatorFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.createMediator(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.configadmin.ConfigurationValidator.validateSequence(ConfigurationValidator.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.configadmin.ConfigurationValidator.validate(ConfigurationValidator.java:73)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.configadmin.ConfigAdmin.validateConfiguration(ConfigAdmin.java:180)
    ... 61 more
    **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngineFactory**
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    atorg.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoa        ..
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 73 more"

***I look up the solution about the same issue you given to other person https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1685 but it doesn't take effect.And I search Google for the question for a long time ,someone said the error has been fixxed or it is something wrong with OSGI Frame when it sets up,but others has the same problem with me still stick in it , so please give us a complete solution about how to use script mediator in WSO2 AM 1.5,tks a lot !***

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the bsf jar which we use to provide scripting engine..As an alternative way, you can use  enrich/payload factory mediator to achieve above task

Comment: Have you try to solve the issue in AM ? Is this in your work plan ? I try to use WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 . The script mediator can be added successfully , so the reason lead to the error must hide in the differences between the ESB and AM. Please have a look in it ,tks,hope to see your answer soon.

Comment: Yes we wil be fixing this in our coming release

Comment: And I want to asks another question ? Besides "mc.getPayloadXML" ,what can be used if i want to extract information from messagebody.

Comment: you can use enrich meditator to access message body using xpath "$body"

Comment: sorg.apache.synapse.mediators.elementary.EnrichMediator is the mediator right?  And it seems that xpath can only process xml message, so I need to transfer the message at first if the content-type isn't xml? would you please give me an example?